# Saving R objects conditional on whether they exist

Tags: r, save, environment, radix

At the end of an analysis I'd like to save some of the R environment objects. However, I reuse this script and sometimes some of the objects don't exist. I don't want to have to edit the save statement each time, so I'd like the script to accommodate when an object doesn't exist. I'm struggling to get this to work with `exist` though.

```
save(if(exists("object1")) {object},
       if(exists("object2")) {object2},
       file = "./my_saved_environment/saved_objects.RData")
```

Comment: when objects doesn't exist, what do you want?  Perhaps, use the `if` outside the `save` i.e. `if(exists("object")) save(object, file = "./my_saved_environment.RData")`

Comment: This is a simplified example, but there are about 30 objects which may or may not exist, so that's a lot of if statements I'd rather avoid. If it doesn't exist I don't want it to try and save it!

Comment: I was thinking that you want to return a message or not if it is not present

Comment: Ah, well a message would be nice yes thakns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `save(file=...)` and a character vector, `intersect`ing with the variables you want. For example:

```r
ls()
# [1] "airquality" "aqm"        "dat"        "mydata"    
intersect(ls(), c("mydata", "quux"))
# [1] "mydata"                                # quux does not exist

save(list = intersect(ls(), c("mydata", "quux")), file = "quux.rda")
```

And if we look at the `.rda` file, this is what is saved:

```r
e <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
load("quux.rda", envir = e)
ls(envir = e)
# [1] "mydata"
```

You can also form the list of objects to save programmatically, perhaps using `grep("^mydata.*", ls(), value=TRUE)` or similar.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks!